# Visual Styles magically stopped working

Tags: c#, visual-styles

Does anyone know what can cause Visual Styles to just stop working? I don't know for sure when it stopped working, so it's hard to go back into time... I checked Program.cs and have EnableVisualStyles()

Yes I check the flatstyle as well...

I also saw, when looking for an answer, that if you run the exe outside of VS it should have Styles... It didn't work.

I created a new project and added all my references and "usings" and visual styles still work so i dont think its any of those things...

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! My Startup Object got changed to the form instead of project.Program which is where EnableVisualStyles() is located.